# Oracle - calculate number of days between two date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two date field, first date_from and date_to.

If I need absence from work (vacation) one days in date_from  and date_to I will put eg. sysdate

This date I will not work.

When try calculate:

```
Select (trunc(sysdate) - to_date(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy.'))  as vacation_days from dual
```

Get result 0, query work fine but realistically I need result 1.

If I need vacation from sysdate to sysdate + 2  this is 3 days but query return 2 days.

```
Select (trunc(sysdate + 2) - to_date(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy.'))  as Total from dual


Select trunc(sysdate) from dual  --20.04.2021.
Select trunc(sysdate + 1) from dual  --21.04.2021.
Select trunc(sysdate + 2) from dual  --22.04.2021.
```

I don't know how smart it is if always in date_to put date one day higher (this day I will work).

In this situation date_from is date when I don't work
date_to is date when I work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` data type as the `TO_DATE` function takes a string as the first argument so Oracle will implicitly convert the `DATE` value to a string and then try to convert it back and this will fail if the format model for the implicit conversion is different from the format model given as the second argument to the `TO_DATE` function (or, worse, it won't fail but will swap the days, months or years arguments).

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT (trunc(sysdate + 2) - to_date(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy.'))  as Total
from dual;
```

Errors with:

> ```
> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> ```

But running the same query with a different implicit date format:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YY.MM.DD';
SELECT (trunc(sysdate + 2) - to_date(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy.'))  as Total
from dual;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TOTAL  |
> | -----: |
> | 730853 |
> ```

This is not what you want as it has implicitly formatted the date to have years then months then days and then read it back expecting days, months and the 4-digit years and gets the date `21-04-0020` rather than `20-04-2021` and you get the valid, but unexpected, result with a difference of about 2000 years and you have used the same query throughout both examples; all that changed is the user has changed a setting in their session to format dates differently and any user can do that in their own session at any time. Do not rely on implicit conversion of dates to strings.

If you want to zero the time component of a `DATE` data type then just use `TRUNC` rather than trying to use `TO_DATE`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3eab2e25371570514924d3fed299e3c9)*

> If I need vacation from sysdate to sysdate + 2 this is 3 days but query return 2 days.

All you need to do is to add 1 to the result:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE + 2 ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 1 AS total FROM DUAL;
```

However, since `SYSDATE - SYSDATE` (or even `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE)`) will always give a value of 0 then you could simplify this to:

```sql
SELECT 3 AS total FROM DUAL;
```